# Windows 7 Adobe Air installation

Tags: air, adobe, windows-installer

i am facing a issue installing Adobe Air. I tried the Adobe Air Troubleshooter
http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/troubleshoot-air-installation-windows.html

but still no solution.

This is the message:

```
An error occurred while installing Adobe AIR. 
Installation may not be allowed by your administrator. 
Please contact your administrator.
```

My OS is Win7

The Runtime installer has some issues as of my understanding but not sure how to fix.

**What i did:**

- CCLEANER REG CLEAN
- UNINSTALL COMPLETE Adobe Sw.
- Standalone installer latest version AdobeAIRInstaller.exe
- Silentmode installation did not work.
- Enabling User Manager did not work.
- Tried old Versions, did not work.

Anyone faced same issues?

Thanks,
Luca

```
####################### INSTALL LOG:
[2013-08-24:13:31:38] Relaunching with elevation
[2013-08-24:13:31:38] Launching subprocess with commandline c:\users\luca\appdata\local\temp\air96e1.tmp\adobe air installer.exe -ei
[2013-08-24:13:31:40] Runtime Installer begin with version 3.8.0.870 on Windows 7 x86
[2013-08-24:13:31:40] Commandline is: -stdio \\.\pipe\AIR_8000_0 -ei
[2013-08-24:13:31:40] No installed runtime detected
[2013-08-24:13:31:40] Starting silent runtime install. Installing runtime version 3.8.0.870
[2013-08-24:13:31:40] Installing msi at c:\users\luca\appdata\local\temp\air96e1.tmp\setup.msi with guid {0A5B39D2-7ED6-4779-BCC9-37F381139DB3}
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Error occurred during msi install operation; beginning rollback: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Rolling back install of c:\users\luca\appdata\local\temp\air96e1.tmp\setup.msi
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Rollback complete
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Exiting due to error: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Exiting due to error: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="1603" errorID=0]
[2013-08-24:13:31:41] Runtime Installer end with exit code 7
[2013-08-24:13:32:11] Runtime Installer end with exit code 7
```

Comment: Do you have administrator privileges on the machine? Did you run the installation as administrator (right click, select 'run as Administrator')?

Answer (score 0):

I have Same Error In Version 1.5.3.1xx
I first update to 1.5.3.2.xx
now you can uninstall , You can find another version in adobe site ,this Do Like Repair
Good Lock